# angular2/Typescript looping over strings, first 1 not formatting as equation (mathJax)

Tags: angular, typescript, mathjax

I am pretty new to angular2 and typescript and now mathJax.

I have an application that when a Calculate button is clicked, retrieves Results from a REST Services endpoint. I then loop through the results to populate the tables. One of the properties is an Equation string. I'm trying to use mathJax to show the equation string as an equation.

The first equation in the loop is not getting formatted, but all those after are formatting just fine. 
What am I missing? Here's a Plunk with a simplified illustration of what's happening.
http://plnkr.co/edit/epnc0r3rqVJhAt0LXmcG?p=preview

(why I need to add code here when I'm adding a plunk is unclear...but ok)

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "MathJax"]);
```

is the code I've found digging around for help adding this library. I think I might be missing something here or in the index.html script configuration of mathJax.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know angular well but it looks like a synchronization issue, i.e., your call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.el.nativeElement]);` fires before the element is in the DOM or gets the math content. For better performance, I would suggest to use the call in your post **after** all math is added to the DOM.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you. I moved that line as the last line in showEquations() and now they all are formatted!